# Аллегорические аллитерации. Что это такое?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Не помню, где я это вычитал, но в памяти сохранилось словосочетание "аллегорические аллитерации". Кто-нибудь может объяснить, что оно означает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аллитерация - повтор (чаще всего в стихах) созвучных сочетаний, для создания ярких образов. Аллегорический - иносказательный. Вместе получается что-то вроде : *иносказательные созвучия*.

> **Аллегорическая аллитерация**
> (Чернышёв Алексей)
> Мистика истины 
> стала историей;
> Вести благие – 
> последним известием.
> Власть предержащие хитрые бестии
> Землю унизили до 
> территории.
> Может, апостолам 
> всё опостылело;
> Иль у божеств 
> проявилось убожество;
> Мужество ли 
> поделилось на множество;
> Звёзды ли сдвинулись; 
> солнце остыло ли;
> В генах ли сгинул 
> заряд гениальности;
> Вирус притворства
> проник ли в творения? –
> Души – 
> отдушины от одурения –
> Даже в реалиях 
> ждут ирреальности.
> Просто: 
> как призраки чьей-то прострации.
> Сложно: 
> как слова и славы слияние…
> Без вожделения, 
> без воздаяния –
> Наглая 
> алгебра 
> аллитерации.

http://www.stihi.ru/2011/04/29/8897

Comment: Вот где бы ещё я узнал ответ на этот вопрос? Большое спасибо!